# 幼いときに老けて、老いて子供に戻る。Can anyone explain the nuances of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, words, quotes

幼いときに老けて、老いて子供に戻る。
I can make a few guesses as to the specific meaning but I'm not sure which one is right.. does anyone know what would be the most correct translation of this sentence?

Comment: What are your guesses?

Comment: Translated very loose, so as to preserve what I am perceiving as the proverb feel:

"As children we grow old, when old we become children again."

or

"Children grow old as the old return to childhood"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hear 老いて子供に戻る a lot, but I haven't heard 幼いときに老けて. Google seems to agree with me, so I'm assuming it's not a proverb or something.

The phrase 幼いときに老けて is rather peculiar because 老ける means "become an old man / behave like a old man" and has a negative nuance. So it's not the same as "grow old"; if you are 幼い and do 老ける, then that's very unusual. It's like an oxymoron, but I don't "get" what is meant here. Perhaps with more context it would make sense, but frankly my guess is that whoever wrote this phrase didn't fully understand the nuance of 老ける.

Comment: Disagreed completely.  The wording 幼い時に老ける may surely be uncommon but I think the author understands the word 老ける.  The sentence makes perfect sense as well.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya If you can make perfect sense of the sentence, you should prob. write an answer...